# Using python to create .bat file and the run the newly created .bat file does not work

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm using Deadline monitor to automate a few processes. I don't think you'll need to know about Deadline to answer my question though.

I've created a Python script that takes a few arguments to be able to create the .bat file. I then want the same python script to run the .bat file to do what I need it to do. However, I'm not having any luck.

```
def main(project_path, nuke_job_id):

    dependencies_file = project_path + "\\" + "dependencies.txt"

    with open(dependencies_file, 'r') as f:
        Job_IDs = f.readlines()

    # ------------- remove unwanted characters

    list_string = str(Job_IDs)
    beginning_ids = list_string.split("[")
    end_ids = beginning_ids[1].split("]")
    job_ids_string = end_ids[0].split("'") # position 1 has what is needed

    # -------------

    temp_id = '636e4b2a518c9b626412f608'

    command = '"%deadline_path%"' + "\\deadlinecommand" + " " + "-SetJobSetting" + " " + temp_id + " " + "JobDependencies" + " " + job_ids_string[1]

    bat_file = open(project_path + "\\" + "create_dependencies.bat", 'w+')
    bat_file.write("@echo off" + "\r\r" + command)
    bat_file.close()

    print ('bat file closed')

    bat_file_to_run = project_path + "\\" + "create_dependencies.bat"


    time.sleep(5)

    run_bat(bat_file_to_run)

    

def run_bat(bat_file_to_run):

    print ("run_bat")

    process = subprocess.Popen(bat_file_to_run, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # process = subprocess.call(bat_file_to_run)
    process.wait()
```

If I run the script as it is, the .bat file is created but then nothing happens.
I tried to manually double click on it to make sure that it works, and interestingly it doesn't work either. However, if I copy the contents of the .bat file into a new one, and then run that one everything works as I want to.

Have I missed something on the automatic creation on the .bat file that it doesn't like it and nothing runs? I've run this script multiple times and I always get the same result. The automatically created .bat file doesn't do anything, but a new one with the exact same contents does work.

I'll share the .bat file code here as well just as reference.

```
@echo off

"%deadline_path%"\deadlinecommand -SetJobSetting 636e4b2a518c9b626412f608 JobDependencies 636e3fb4d4682e9cb0790c47,636e3fbf76741b65388982ae,636e3fcc4ad53e99c0426f2a,636e3fd846409c9d10aff124,636e3fe5e740b57ee4e48ef7,636e3ff57883fc8c10294a0b,636e4000f47c7671583bfe1d,636e400b885d6e8970186399,636e40176be6ce9d80ce357c,636e4021b75ec99c8074b34b
```

I tried adding a pause at the end to be able to see what's happening, but it doesn't do it either. And like I said, if I create the .bat file manually, it works just as expected.

Thank you for your time. Hopefully someone will be able to point me in the right direction as I don't really know what's happening or why it's happening.

Comment: Are you certain that's the batch file content?  Where and how was `%deadline_path%` defined? and what is its content? Why do you need to run a batch file, when you're already running a more powerful scripting language?

Comment: %deadline_path% was defined in the installation of Deadline in the machine. It's an env variable to be able to access Deadline's modules and be able to talk to Deadline from outside of Deadline. The reason why I'm having to run a batch file is because the contents of the file are created at different stages of my process. The file is created at stage 4, but I cannot run that process until I reach stage 6, so the easiest way was to do that.

Comment: Nonetheless, your batch file appears only to be running a file with arguments, so why can python not run a file with arguments? I see no purpose in involving a batch file at all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the newly created .bat file has some hidden text characters in it that causes the batch file to fail?

https://www.w3schools.io/editor/notepad++-view-hidden-chars/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was related to another one of the answers I got.

Essentially I'm creating a batch file inside of Python. The way I was creating using backslash + r. Like this:

```
bat_file = open(project_path + "\\" + "create_dependencies.bat", 'w+')
bat_file.write("@echo off" + "\r\r" + command)
bat_file.close()
```

When looking at hidden text characters, I saw that the one I created manually added a "carriage return" and a "line feed".
The one that was created automatically only created a "carriage return" because I was using "\r".
All I had to do was change the code to use "\n" and the batch file started working as expected.